# Parsing and Storing Tokens in C program

Tags: c, arrays

So for my problem, if someone types something, I parse it and store it into a character array. I am separating whatever the user types by space. Then I store these tokens into the char array and print it out. But for some reason, after printing the first word, some gibberish is getting printed out.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLINE 80

int main(void) {
    char *args[MAXLINE / 2 + 1];
    char buf[MAXLINE / 2 + 1];
    scanf("%s", buf);
    int i;
    char *token;
    token = strtok(buf, " ");
    while (token != NULL) {
        args[i++] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    //to print the array
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(*args); i++) {
        printf("%s\n" args[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please lay out your code properly.  You're missing at least one `}`.  Also, you never initialised `i` to zero before using it, so that might be your problem.  Best to copy and paste your actual _compiling_ code in here than attempt to type it out again.  There is no variable named `buf`.  You apparently declared one called `but`.

Comment: You need to have **buf+=(token+1)** after the first strtok() invocation. The +1 takes you to the right of the seperating space.

Comment: @ArifBurhan No, you don't have to because `buf` is no longer used.

Comment: `strlen(*args)` gives the the length of the first string. That's clearly not what you want. Instead, at that point, `i` already contains the number of valid entries stored in `args` and should be used as the max number of iterations for that loop.

Comment: `char buf [MAXLINE/2 + 1];
    scanf("%s", buf);int i;` --> `char buf [MAXLINE + 1];
    scanf("%[^\n]", buf);int i=0;`

Comment: There is a missing , in `printf("%s\n" args[i]);`

Comment: @chqrlie it's typo. because can't compile it.

Comment: @ArifBurhan You mustn't have `buf+=(token+1)` because `buf` is an array and this expression will emit compile error.

Answer (score 1):

There a several problems in your code:

- `char buf[MAXLINE / 2 + 1];` seems incorrect, the buffer size should be `MAXLINE+1`.
- you read a string with `scanf("%s", buf)`: such a string will not contain any space character.  Trying to parse it with `strtok` will always produce a single token, except at the end of file, which you do not test for. You should use `fgets()` instead.
- `i` is uninitialized, storing a pointer to `args[i++]` invokes undefined behavior. `i` should be initialized to `0`.
- The loop condition at the end is incorrect: `i < strlen(*args)` does not make sense, you should instead use a different index and loop from `0` to `i`.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLINE 80

int main(void) {
    char *args[MAXLINE / 2];
    char buf[MAXLINE + 1];

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
        int i = 0, j;
        char *token = strtok(buf, " \t\n");
        while (token != NULL) {
            args[i++] = token;
            token = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
        }
        //to print the array
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            printf("%s\n" args[j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess thid should be a comment because this is not an answer to the main question.

Comment: @StephCurry3093:  can you please click on the grey check mark below the answer score to mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

- You have to initialize `i` befote using its value, or you will invoke *undefined behavior*.
- `strlen(*argv)` won't give the number of tokens. You have to save the number.
- `scanf()` will do the parsing for you, so you won't need `strtok()`

corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 80

int main(void){
    char * args[MAXLINE/2 + 1];
    char buf [MAXLINE/2 + 1];
    int i = 0, num;
    char *token;
    token = buf;
    while(scanf("%s", token) == 1){
        args[i++] = token;
        token += strlen(token) + 1;
    }
    num = i;

    //to print the array
    for(i = 0; i < num;i++){
        printf("%s\n", args[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code only seems to print out the first word. For example, if user types Hello World, it'll only print out Hello

Comment: I was able to get it working by using fgets(buf,MAXLINE,stdin) instead of scanf. But there seems to be an extra space that gets printed out at the end

Comment: @StephCurry3093 Thank you, nice point. Isn't the "extra space" the newline read by `fgets()`?

Comment: @StephCurry3093 `strtok(XXXX, " ");` : delimiter change  `" "` to `" \n"`

Comment: I am not really sure. I am pretty new to C. Have mostly programmed in Java. But I am guessing so

Comment: @MikeCAT: interesting minimalistic use of `scanf` for parsing... but I don't see an easy way to make it safe from buffer overflows.